# How to test banker algorithm and show other ordering has problem

Tags: algorithm

I have found a Python version of the banker algorithm on GeeksForGeeks site [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bankers-algorithm-in-operating-system-2/).

However, how to test and show that the safe ordering is correct?

And how to show that other orderings have an error or problem with an example?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bankers-algorithm-in-operating-system-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's consider a very simple example. Let's say there are `2` processes - P<sub>0</sub> and P<sub>1</sub>, and there's only one type of resource `A`. The system allocates `10` units of `A` to P<sub>0</sub> and `0` to P<sub>1</sub>, and it still has `1` unit of `A` left. Moreover, in total , P<sub>0</sub> may request up to `11` units during the execution, and P<sub>1</sub> - `5`.

Let's quickly build up tables and vectors used to determine safe or unsafe sequences for these processes.

#### Allocation table

Allocation table shows how many resources of each type are allocated to processes. In your example, it looks as follows:

| Process | A |
| --- | --- |
| P<sub>0</sub> | 10 |
| P<sub>1</sub> | 0 |

#### Availability vector

Availability vector shows how many units the system can still offer if it decides so.

| A |
| --- |
| 1 |

#### Maximum table

Maximum table shows how many units of `A` each process may request during the execution (in total).

| Process | A |
| --- | --- |
| P<sub>0</sub> | 11 |
| P<sub>1</sub> | 5 |

#### Need table

Need table shows how many units of `A` each process may additionally request during the execution

| Process | A |
| --- | --- |
| P<sub>0</sub> | 1 |
| P<sub>1</sub> | 5 |

## Safe sequence

Now, let's say we ran the Banker's algorithm for our configuration and got the following sequence:

> P<sub>0</sub> -> P<sub>1</sub>

Why is it safe?

### Case 1 - processes are executed in sequence

P<sub>0</sub> starts executing, and demands and receives the remaining `1` unit. So, the system has `0` available resources left. However, once P<sub>0</sub> completes, it releases `11` units of `A`, and it's more than enough to run P<sub>1</sub> and for it to complete.

### Case 2 - processes are executed in parallel

P<sub>0</sub> starts executing, and demands and receives the remaining `1` unit. Then, during its execution, P<sub>1</sub> starts too and asks for `5` units. However, its request gets postponed because the system has none. So, the request is put on a waiting list. Later, when P<sub>0</sub> releases at least `5` units, P<sub>1</sub> finally gets `5`. Obviously, no deadlock can happen because if P<sub>0</sub> needs resources again, it will either wait for P<sub>1</sub> or just ask the system and vice versa.

## Unsafe sequence

> P<sub>1</sub> -> P<sub>0</sub>

P<sub>1</sub> starts executing and demands `5` units from the system. It gets denied and its request is put on a waiting list because the system has only `1` unit. Then, P<sub>0</sub> starts and demands `1` unit. It also gets denied because P<sub>1</sub> is waiting for `5` units already. The request from P<sub>0</sub> is put on the waiting list too. So, we have a deadlock situation because neither of the requests can ever go through.